# How to use Spring's ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean factory bean

Tags: java, spring, factory

I would like to be able to inject an `ExecutorService` instance into my Spring services, and the Spring API suggest using `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` for this purpose. Very simple question; how the hell do I use the `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` to create an `ExecutorService` that I can wire into my other services?

I feel like a complete idiot for asking his question, but I can't seem to get this figured out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you need to learn what a `FactoryBean` is - read [section 3.8.3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) of the spring docs.

Then, you read the [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean.html) for `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` and understand what it does.

Next, you configure a `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` in your context. This will create an `ExecutorService` (since it's a `FactoryBean`, see above), which you can inject into your bean.

Comment: I had somehow convinced myself that objects created by the factory beans needed to be wrapped in another Spring bean. Injecting it directly worked, doh! Thanks =)

Answer (score 9):

To expand on [skaffman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083488/474189), here's a short and sweet example of what one needs to do:

```xml
<bean id="classNeedingExecutor" class="foo.Bar">
  <property name="executor" ref="threadExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="threadExecutor"
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="1" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Again, see the [JavaDocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean.html) for an explanation of the other properties that can be set to configure the `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 6):

You may consider using @Async if you're using spring 3, http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/08/spring-asynchronous-support/.

Comment: Really? A downvote? I think spring's task namespace + the @Async annotation makes working with threads really conveneint. It might not be exactly what pHk was looking for but it's useful information nonetheless.

Comment: +1 I appreciate learning of better solutions that take a different path than I'm trying to follow. Sometimes the answer to "How do I hook up a firehose to a paint sprayer?" is "Don't use a firehose to paint your house!"

Comment: I down voted this because that could be an answer to every question concerning Spring and multi-threading, and it's really not an answer to my question. I thought my question was specific enough to avoid generic replies. In retrospect, maybe a downvote was a little harsh, and my question did not indicate clearly that I wasn't looking for general advice on how to use Spring for multi-threading.

Comment: @Doug Good job shoeing in a personal insult that's really uncalled for. Also, try to read the question, comments and answers before you try to crucify me and (quite ironically) call me a "jerk".